REST API CRUD Operations design for a complex resource
I have a requirement to create a REST API for managing a Connections resource. Connections can be of different types like HTTP, Database, SOAP etc. I am using abstractions and inheritance in OpenAPI at the moment.
However, I wanted to validate if the design is correct. Mainly because a few fields are sensitive and I want to encrypt them before saving to DB. Also, I do not want to return these fields in the response of the GET API's , but I Do want to allow updating the sensitive fields if required.
Current swagger spec:
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: Connections API
  version: "1.0"
servers:
- url: /api/v1
security:
- bearerAuth: []
paths:
  /tenants/{tenant_id}/management/connections:
    post:
      tags:
      - Connections
      operationId: createConnection
      summary: Create a connection
      description: Create a new Connection for external system integration
      parameters:
      - name: tenant_id
        in: path
        required: true
        schema:
          type: string
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/ConnectionCreateRequest'
        required: false
      responses:
        "201":
          description: Connection was created successfully
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/ConnectionReadResponse'
          headers:
            ETag:
              description: An entity tag representing the resource version
              schema:
                type: string
        "422":
          description: Unprocessable Entity
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/HTTPValidationError'
    get:
      tags:
      - Connections
      operationId: getConnections
      summary: Retrieve all Connections for the Tenant
      description: "The API returns Connections according to the input filter. In case filter is not provided the API returns the latest Connections.\n\n The filter sets criteria for retrieving a subset of resources from a collection, using JSON Path syntax to express the conditions for retrieval. The filter consists of <attribute in json path format><required operator><value>, if there are more than one attribute in the condition the sign '&' will appear between the parts. if there there are several conditions with 'or' operator between them they will be separated with ';'. In case of operator 'equals', several values can be provided separated by comma ','. Filter format: filter=[attributeName][operator][value],?,[value][&|;]?[&|;][attributeName][operator][value],?,[value]\n\n Currently this API supports filtering by the attribute 'id' and the operator equals '==' only. For example: 'id==1234', in this case 2 documents are supposed to be retrieved with the relevant id" 
      parameters:
      - name: tenant_id
        in: path
        required: true
        schema:
          type: string
      - name: filter
        in: query
        required: false
        schema:
          type: string
      - name: limit
        in: query
        required: false
        schema:
          type: integer
      - name: offset
        in: query
        required: false
        schema:
          type: integer
      responses:
        "200":
          description: Connections were retrieved successfuly
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/ConnectionReadResponse'
          headers:
            X-Total-Count:
              schema:
                type: number
              description: Specify the total number of resources that are applied to the query.
      x-codegen-request-body-name: connection
  /tenants/{tenant_id}/management/internal/connections/{connection_id}:
    get:
      tags:
      - Connections
      operationId: getConnectionById
      summary: Get a Connection by ID. 
      description: Retrieve the Connection by connection ID.
      parameters:
      - name: tenant_id
        in: path
        required: true
        schema:
          type: string
      - name: connection_id
        in: path
        required: true
        schema:
          type: string
      responses:
        "200":
          description: The Connection was retrieved successfully
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/ConnectionReadResponse'
          headers:
            ETag:
              description: An entity tag representing the resource version
              schema:
                type: string
        "404":
          description: Connection not found
          content: {}
      x-amaiz-internal-api: true    
  /tenants/{tenant_id}/management/connections/{connection_id}:    
    put:
      tags:
      - Connections
      operationId: updateConnectionById
      summary: Update a Connection by ID
      description: Update the Connection by ID. If the connection is being used by multiple steps, the update will impact all the steps that use this Connection. If the Connection is not found, will return appropriate status code.
      parameters:
      - name: tenant_id
        in: path
        required: true
        schema:
          type: string
      - name: connection_id
        in: path
        required: true
        schema:
          type: string
      - name: If-Match
        in: header
        required: false
        schema:
          type: string
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/ConnectionCreateRequest'
        required: false
      responses:
        "200":
          description: The Connection was updated successfully
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/ConnectionReadResponse'
          headers:
            ETag:
              description: An entity tag representing the resource version
              schema:
                type: string
        "404":
          description: Connection was not found
          content: {}
        "422":
          description: Unprocessable Entity
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/HTTPValidationError'
    delete:
      tags:
      - Connections
      operationId: deleteConnectionById
      summary: Delete a Connection by ID
      description: Delete a Connection by ID. If the Connection is being used by Apps, the Connection should be first unlinked from all applications. If the Connection is linked to an application, the api will return an error.
      parameters:
      - name: tenant_id
        in: path
        required: true
        schema:
          type: string
      - name: connection_id
        in: path
        required: true
        schema:
          type: string
      responses:
        "204":
          description: Connection was deleted successfully
          content: {}
        "404":
          description: Connection not found
          content: {}
        "409":
          description: Connection cannot be deleted as it is being used by other applications
          content: {}
components:
  securitySchemes:
    bearerAuth:            
      type: http
      scheme: bearer
      bearerFormat: JWT
  schemas:
    HTTPValidationError:
      properties:
        detail:
          items:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/ValidationError'
          type: array
          title: Detail
      type: object
      title: HTTPValidationError
    ValidationError:
      properties:
        loc:
          items:
            anyOf:
              - type: string
              - type: integer
          type: array
          title: Location
        msg:
          type: string
          title: Message
        type:
          type: string
          title: Error Type
      type: object
      required:
        - loc
        - msg
        - type
      title: ValidationError
    ConnectionCreateRequest:
      type: object
      required:
        - name
        - description
        - type
        - details
      properties:
        name:
          type: string
        description:
          type: string
        type:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/ConnectionType'
        details:
          oneOf:
            - $ref: '#/components/schemas/HttpConnectionDetails'
    ConnectionDetails:
      type: object
      required:
        - env_type
      properties:
        env_type:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/EnvType'
    EnvType:
      type: string
      enum:
        - DEV
        - TESTING
        - PRODUCTION
    HttpConnectionDetails:
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/ConnectionDetails'
      type: object
      required:
        - base_url
        - auth_type
        - auth_details
      properties:
        base_url:
          type: string
        auth_type:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/HttpAuthType'
        auth_details:
          oneOf:
            - $ref: '#/components/schemas/OAuth2ClientCred'
            - $ref: '#/components/schemas/OAuth2AuthCode'
            - $ref: '#/components/schemas/ApiKey'
            - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Basic'
            - $ref: '#/components/schemas/NoAuth'
    ConnectionReadResponse:
      type: object
      required:
        - id
        - name
        - description
        - type
        - control_fields
      properties:
        id:
          type: string
        name:
          type: string
        description:
          type: string
        type:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/ConnectionType'
        details:
          type: array
          items:
            oneOf:
              - $ref: '#/components/schemas/HttpConnectionDetails'
        control_fields:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/ControlFields'
    HttpAuth:
      type: object
      required:
        - auth_type
        - ssl_enabled
      properties:
        auth_type:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/HttpAuthType'
        ssl_enabled:
          type: boolean
    NoAuth:
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/HttpAuth'
      type: object
    OAuth2ClientCred:
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/HttpAuth'
      type: object
      required:
      - token_url
      - client_id
      - client_secret
      properties:
        token_url:
          type: string
        client_id:
          type: string
        client_secret:
          type: string
    OAuth2AuthCode:
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/HttpAuth'
      type: object
      required:
      - auth_url
      - token_url
      - client_id
      - client_secret
      properties:
        auth_url:
          type: string
        token_url:
          type: string
        client_id:
          type: string
        client_secret:
          type: string
    ApiKey:
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/HttpAuth'
      type: object
      required:
      - api_key
      - header_key
      properties:
        api_key:
          type: string
        header_key:
          type: string
    Basic:
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/HttpAuth'
      type: object
      required:
      - username
      - password
      properties:
        username:
          type: string
        password:
          type: string
    ConnectionType:
      type: string
      enum:
      - http
    HttpAuthType:
      type: string
      enum:
      - no_auth
      - oauth2_client_cred
      - oauth2_auth_code
      - api_key
      - basic
    ControlFields:
      type: object
      properties:
        created_by:
          type: string
        updated_by:
          type: string
        created_on:
          type: string
        last_updated_on:
          type: string
    Headers:
      type: object
      additionalProperties:
        type: string
    CreateConnection:
      type: object
      required:
        - response
      properties:
        response:
          $ref: "#/components/schemas/ConnectionReadResponse"
        headers:
          $ref: "#/components/schemas/Headers"
    GetConnections:
      type: object
      required:
        - response
      properties:
        response:
          type: array
          items:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/ConnectionReadResponse'
        headers:
          $ref: "#/components/schemas/Headers"
    GetConnectionById:
      type: object
      required:
        - response
      properties:
        response:
          $ref: "#/components/schemas/ConnectionReadResponse"
        headers:
          $ref: "#/components/schemas/Headers"
    UpdateConnectionById:
      type: object
      required:
        - response
      properties:
        response:
          $ref: "#/components/schemas/ConnectionReadResponse"
        headers:
          $ref: "#/components/schemas/Headers"


x-original-swagger-version: "2.0"

Would appreciate any suggestions if this could be improved
I have created a design, but want to validate it
